# Eclipse Oxygen fails to run - org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access

Tags: java-9, bndtools, eclipse-oxygen

I have following problem: my eclipse Oxygen fails to run(error attached).
Everything is fine on fresh instalation, when I run it just after downloading (tested on 1a september and 2 december). However, when i restart my computer, eclipse won't start again unless i will reinstall it.
I have cleared both eclipse cache as same as my project (even fetched fresh version from repo), workspace and eclipse instalation place is also fresh.
I have read e.g. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475392, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=514895 and other related posts, didn't help though.
Any idea? I am working on windows 10 64 bit, and JDK 9.0.1+11. My only plugin is BndTools 3.5, latest, project requires java 8 (current runtime jdk is 152).
Problem started on friday, 15 dec after running my project and resolving dependencies at example bnd project (http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_base/600-testing.html) at the same time. Couldn't run eclipse after that.
However, i did it before and didn't meet any problems (i mean opening example and running it). Also, I have cleared p2, mvn and bnd cache.

Below mentioned stack from eclipse .log:

```
!SESSION 2017-12-18 16:47:57.660 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.2.M20171123-0800
java.version=9.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pl_PL
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-18 16:47:59.711
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1263)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDevice(Display.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.addListener(Display.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.<init>(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.<init>(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
```

[Diff between fresh and dirty instalation](https://www.diffchecker.com/TOYvQPao)

---

## Update

After flushing whole system, problem gone for a while, however came back again, so it eliminates OS influence in my opinion.
As [Struarf mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48154427/6332692), deletion of `configuration/org.eclipse.osgi` **templorary** solves problem.
Nevertheless, when i have installed oxygen 2, I noticed that this problem is much more rarer than before (actually now 2nd time for 2 weeks, whether before was with each possible occasion), so maybe it comes in a good way...

Comment: Something related that was posted yesterday itself. https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1090654&goto=1778570&

Comment: Yes, i have seen that, but that guy is using 32 bit win 7 so it is understandable... :/ Thx although.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just commented on bug 477247. I'm getting a similar exception (on OSX).  What allows me to start Eclipse without reinstalling is to delete the configuration/org.eclipse.osgi folder.  It looked like a bundle cache, and deleting such caches has worked elsewhere for me.  Hopefully this might also provide a clue for the devs.

Comment: Saved me. Thanks. 
Showed up out of the blue after restarting Eclipse and enabling Windows Firewall. 
IT had also done some changes to my machine and asked me to reboot-- but I doubt that contributed to the issue, though it might have.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to hit [bug 477247](http://bugs.eclipse.org/477247). Until now, Eclipse developers were not able to reproduce the issue, maybe you can help them by adding steps to reproduce to the bug, or any other useful details.

Comment: Thank you for sharing.
I also used an installable version of Eclipse Oxygen (1a september) and that worked longer, however everything repeated (but after longer time so... accident or hint?). My idea is that eclipse is caching something deep in windows or it have a conflict with windows in some locales (PL)... just ideas. Or with other apps (i have intellij for example). WIll check later.

Comment: Anything that helps reproducing is highly appreciated!

Comment: I have added difference in folder and files structure

Comment: The main message I take from the linked difference is: ECLIPSEINVALID has bndtools installed, whereas ECLIPSENEW does not. So, did you see the problem also without bndtools? If you comment in the Eclipse bug, people may ask other questions which may be more effective in identifying the culprit.